# xmlbeans-marshaller is depricated in spring 5

Tags: java, spring

xmlbeans-marshaller is depricated in spring version 5

As xmlbeans-marshaller is depricated in spring version 5, I still want to use xmlbeans-marshaller. What should i do ?

Comment: You should read this https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/Marshaller.html

Comment: Thank for replying, but can you please let me know howi can i still use xmlbeans-marshaller ?  or need to use jaxb2-marshaller.

Comment: Kindly post your code so that we could know in what way we can replace the marshaller. A snippet would make even better.

Comment: Have you been able to solve your problem?